React image referencing
I use React. I wrote this for referencing an image, but it doesn't work.
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "../src/logo.jpg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="columns">
        <img src={logo} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

The logo.jpg file is in src/ folder
I expected the image to show up but all I get is a blank page, no error code, just blank page.

Why do you need all the React-router bits? You don't seem to be declaring any routes.

The Dom I guess? I will delete it. I am new in React

Wouldn't assets go into a public (static) directory?

this didn`t change a thing.

I've replicated your code in a codesandbox and it renders the image just fine for me. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-78367436-gd8rzd?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js
